# Marquee text over an image in html

Tags: html, css, marquee

I want a text to scroll from up to down over an image in top-right corner in my webpage. But I am not able to place the text over image. Thanks in advance

```
<div id="display">
    <img height="210" width="160" src="note1.gif" />
    <marquee id="m1" onMouseOver="stopM()" onMouseOut="startM()" scrollamount="2" direction="up" loop="true" width="30%">
    <center>
    <p id="text">
    Opening Soon !!!
    </p>
    </center>
    </marquee>
    </div>
```

This is my css code

```
#display { 
        position:absolute; 
        visibility:show; 
        left: 73%; 
        top: 2%;        
        }
#text
{
     color:Black;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:65%;
    top:2%;
}
```

Comment: [This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

Comment: Both the center and marquee tags were deprecated ages ago. And I'm pretty sure they're both removed from HTML5.

Comment: Marquee is obsolete and deprecated. Other than that, you have other problems like obtrusive javascript, other deprecated tags like center, etc. I suggest you to study up some modern html/css/js.

Comment: @j08691 Technically, `marquee` isn't deprecated because it was never added to the HTML spec in the first place.

Comment: @Blazemonger "The marquee element is originally an IE invention." No wonder

Comment: Thank you friends for your suggestion. I will try to implement using js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll avoid commenting on the validity of your HTML, and stick solely to solving your problem here.

## [This fiddle should solve your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/n9thytwv/)

**CSS**

```
#display 
{ 
     position:absolute; 
     visibility:show; 
     left: 73%; 
     top: 2%;
}
#text
{
    color:Black;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:65%;
    top:2%;
}
marquee {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to place the text in the middle of my image. It's not getting placed

Comment: Set a `width` on `#display` of say `160px` and then set a `width: 100%` rule on marquee.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to absolutely-position the image behind the other elements:

```
#display { position: relative; }
#display img { position: absolute; }
```

or move your image into a background:

```
#display { 
   background-image: url(note1.gif);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

That said, please note (as others have pointed out) that [`<marquee>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) is a non-standard tag and [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) has been long since deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, change your CSS to

```
#display { 
        position: relative 
        visibility:show; 
        overflow:hidden;
       height: 210px;
       width: 160px;

        }

#display img { 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;

}

#display marquee { 
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;

}



#text
{
     color:Black;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:65%;
    top:2%;
}
```

[See working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/2tmo5nwn/)

Comment: what to do if I want the text to just go halfway across the background image

Comment: Wrap it in a DIV, then make the DIV half the height of the image or  simply use the "top" property value to adjust it.

Comment: can you help me with top property

Comment: Check the fiddle again. See how I adjusted the CSS

Answer (score 0):

this is working code .. hope so help you

```html
<div id="marquee" style="margin-top: 5%;" >
       <marquee id="marquee2" scrollamount="5" loop="infinite" bgcolor="white"  onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
       <div style="float: left; padding: 5px;">
        <a href="#"><img src="karachi.jpg"  style="height: 200px; width: 200px;" >
        </a>
        <div >
        <h2>MULTAN </h2>
        
        </div></div>
        <div style="float: left;">
        <a href="#"><img src="karachi.jpg"  style="height: 200px; width: 200px;" >
        </a>
        <div >
        <h2>LAHORE </h2>
        
        </div></div>
        
       </marquee>
    
    </div>
```

### MULTAN

### LAHORE